# Show pairs of files with same m5dsum

Tags: scripting, hashsum

I need to calculate md5sum of all files in a directory and print them in a line if their md5sum is same. for example, if we calculate md5sums:

```
file1, md5sum abcdefgh    
file2, md5sum 21safdsg
file3, md5sum abcdefgh
file4, md5sum 21safdsg
```

the output should look like this:

```
file1, file3, abcdefgh
file2, file4, 21safdsg
```

It can be a script or a command. I've run out of ideas.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: loop over all files (`for file do`), and append (`>>`) md5sum to a log file. After loop check for identical md5sum values in logfile. (helpful: `sort` and `join`). Give it a few tries.

Comment: I would try something like `files=()
while read -r -d ''; do
    files+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find . -exec {} \;)`  then loop through `files` numeric array.within that loop,  start a subloop based on the same `files` array. for each item in the sub loop do a conditional checking you are not comparing the same file against itself, if not, compare the md5sum if the subloop item with the main loop item if they are the same - print the filename and you are done.

Comment: @the_velour_fog Yes I thought of doing it your way, however I don't know how to create such an array. Could you please provide me any further help?

Comment: *give a UNIX programmer an array, and he stores data for a day, TEACH a UNIX programmer arrays and he stores data for a lifetime.*  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
cat output
file1, md5sum abcdefgh    
file2, md5sum 21safdsg
file3, md5sum abcdefgh
file4, md5sum 21safdsg

awk -F, '{split($2,a," "); f[a[2]]=$1" "f[a[2]]} END { for (x in f) { sub(/ /,",",f[x]); print f[x],x } } ' output

file4,file2  21safdsg
file3,file1  abcdefgh
```

Comment: Yeah, it does :) Great! Could you briefly explain what does it to?
I assume it creates an array, but i'm not sure what happens next

Comment: so, i take the array/hash (a[2] element), and keep appending filename $1 to it. Then i ready thru the hash and show how many times it occurred.